# Trying to re-post a question to find an answer

Tags: support

This stuff is really difficult.

How do i make my editted question visable again so that i may hope to find an answer since im not able to post again?

Comment: have you considered a bounty? (and link the question here, just for publicity ...)

Comment: Not familiar with bounty.  Ill look into it.  Thank you for your kind help

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

Comment: Editing the question bumps it in the active queue. Anyone accessing the site through http://physics.stackexchange.com/ will see it at the top again.

Comment: Okay.  Thank you for your kind help

Comment: I'd add to what @dmckee said that you shouldn't make a trivial edit to a question _only_ for the sake of bumping it. Any edit you make needs to actually improve the question.

Answer (score 2):

Any edits to any post will bump it to the top of the front page. Note, however, that minor edits meant solely to bump a question (i.e. take attention away from questions with actual recent activity) are *not* welcome on this site. The edit rate for [your latest question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265670/why-precisely-do-we-use-regulators-for-infinite-sums) - nine edits in 45 min - is pretty close to the border, but I'm more put off by the belligerence of the text than by any trivial bump edits.

Any edits within five days of closure will also put the question on a review queue for reopen votes, which typically clears quite quickly. The [review page for your question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/136911) shows that three independent people thought it was not clear enough for re-opening, so it's left the queue now. I'm unsure whether another edit will put it back on the queue but if you do edit it then please make a single, comprehensive edit instead of a series of belligerent ones.

I should also ask you to keep down the formatting emphasis. If everything is emphasized, nothing is (and, instead, you get a rather jarring, irritating, and hard to read post, for no reason at all).

If you want to draw attention to a question, the best way is to use a [bounty](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). However, I would advise you at present not to spend your reputation points on that; for a bounty to be useful the question needs to be phrased in a way that lets the community know what sort of answer you're expecting (and also in a way that doesn't make potential answerers think that the only thing they've got to gain by posting is a long, angry discussion). I don't think your question's problems at the moment are lack of attention, to be honest - but it's up to you to solicit people's time and help on how to phrase the question in a constructive way.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help.  I will stick to answering questions and avoid asking questions in the future

Comment: I get the impression that some people are just being jerks for no reason. Im truly truly truly baffled by how to ask the question any more clearly. It's just bizarre to me. Am i being goaded into making edits when editing a lot is disaollowed?

Comment: I can't comment on other people's behaviour as it seems that several of those comments have been deleted. I won't comment on your question, either - that looks like a long, ongoing, very weary discussion I'm not at all keen to join.